# Query the database to check if the email provided in the invitation model already exists in the user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have successfully implemented an invite feature in my app. Each user has_many scoreboards and each scoreboard has_many invitations. The invitation model has two columns, recipient_name and recipient_email and an invitation email is sent to the recipient_email. All these features are working perfectly fine. The controller code for the create action is given below.

```
** scoreboard 
** has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => "Invitation"
def create
    @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
    @invitation = @scoreboard.sent_invitations.build(invitation_params)
    if @invitation.save  # and the recipient_email doesn't exist in the user model database
                         # send the sign_up email
      UserMailer.invitation_email(@invitation, @scoreboard).deliver_now
      flash[:success] = "Invitation sent"
      redirect_to new_scoreboard_invitation_path

    #elsif
      # if the user exists in the database
      # send the email saying they've been invited to view a scoreboard

    else
      render new_scoreboard_invitation_path
    end
  end
end
```

As an extension of the feature, I also want to query the database to check if the recipient_email provided in the invitation model exists in the user model (column :email). I have emails set as unique when the user signs up, therefore, searching for the email will reveal whether the user is registered or not.

The problem is that I am not sure how to check if the recipient_email present in the invitation_table also exists in the user_table. I have tried several things. 
I have tried saving the recipient_email's most recent record in a local variable and then querying the database for that record. I didn't think that was the correct way to implement this.

I also tested the code given below in the invitation's new action with a simple if and else statement to see what would happen. However, every time I send an email to a registered or non-registered user, It always prints "no". I am not exactly sure exactly how to approach this correctly. I know the exists? method would be used somewhere but not sure how to really use it. I have tried to keep it to the point and included the relevant pieces of code. However, if I missed anything, I can definitely include that. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!!

```
   <% if User.where("email = ?", @invitation.recipient_email).exists? %>
    <%= "Yes" %>
   <% else %>
    <%= "no" %>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your usage of the .exists? method, but you're actually calling it incorrectly. The condition (which you have as a .where statement) is actually meant to be passed to the .exists? function as a parameter.

So, instead of saying:

```
if User.where("email = ?", @invitation.recipient_email).exists?
```

You actually want to say:

```
if User.exists?( email: @invitation.recipient_email )
```

.exists? takes a hash of field names paired with values. For more detail on the exists? method, [see the official documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class).

**Addendum**

Regarding the hash notation (being passed to the .exists? method), in the most recent versions of Rails the "standard" way of passing parameters to ActiveRecord methods is in hash form. There are, however, certainly times when it is appropriate to use the question mark interpolation method you chose to employ. I'm only offering this comment to alleviate any confusion between the two different method calls. Each of the following would perform the same query:

```
.where("field = ?", value)
.where(:field => value)
.where(field: value)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I'll definitely give the documentation a read. Thanks once again.